# Get Value Combobox ExtJs From View to Controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, view, combobox, controller

i dont know ho to get value from a view to controller in ExtJs. maybe somebody know ho to.. help me here..
 This is my view **Order_v2.js**

```
formSelectProduct: function(seq, name) {
        var panel = {
            id: 'card-' + seq,
            name: name,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'label',
                html: '<h1>Anda mengklik lokasi instalasi.'
            }, {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                fieldLabel: 'Produk',
                store: 'Products',
                name: 'productId',
                mode: 'queryMode',
                displayField: 'productName',
                valueField: 'productValue',
                typeAhead: true,
                forceSelection: true,
                emptyText: 'Pilih Produk...',
                width: 350,
                labelWidth:90,
                id: 'pilih',
                triggerAction: 'all',
                margin: '10 0 0 0',
                value: '4',
                hidden: true
            },
{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Check Feasibility',
                action: 'doFeasibility',
                margin: '10 0 0 0'
            }
```

i want to get value from combo box and show it on alert when i click the button. i made the function in controller.
and this is controller

```
 refs: [
        { ref: 'formSelectProduct', selector: 'cmsorder > container[name=orderPanel] > form[name=formSelectProduct]' },
.......
this.control({
            'cmsorder > toolbar[name=statusBar] > button[action=doCancel]': {
                click: this.doCancel
            },

            'cmsorder > container > form[name=formSelectProduct] > button[action=doFeasibility]': {
                click: this.doFeasibility
            },
.......
doFeasibility: function() {
var me=this,
         formSelectProduct =me.getFormSelectProduct();
        var combo=formSelectProduct.down('combobox[name=productId]');
        var a=combo.getValue();
        Ext.Msg.alert("Produk yang anda Pilih",a);
    },
```

the resut just show alert without show combo box value.. anyone can help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work..

```
var a=combo[0].getValue();
```

In my view ".down" method is query method which returns an array of Ext components with matching selector. So, index will be required to get value of the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this it will work. Using ID of the component/Element from EXT/DOM  which provides the feature to access any element from any where.Ext.getCmp() helps to search element on the basis of the id assign to the component.

`var combo=Ext.getCmp('pilih');
var a=combo.getValue();
Ext.Msg.alert("Produk yang anda Pilih",a);`

Comment: This has been flagged as low-quality. Perhaps you should add some explanation about what your code does exactly, or your answer could be deleted by the community.